# Convergence of an infinite sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, nested-radicals

I want to know if
$$
B=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{4+\sqrt{8+\sqrt{16+...}}}}
$$
converges to a finite value or not. $B$ can be written as 
$$
B=\sqrt{2^1+\sqrt{2^2+\sqrt{2^3+\sqrt{2^4+...}}}}.
$$ 
However, I have no idea the next step. Any suggestion, idea, or comment is welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have

$$B=\sqrt{2^1+\sqrt{2^2+\sqrt{2^3+\sqrt{2^4+\cdots}}}}<\sqrt{2^{2^0}+\sqrt{2^{2^1}+\sqrt{2^{2^2}+\sqrt{2^{2^3}+\cdots}}}}$$

We then note that

$$A=\sqrt{2^{2^0}+\sqrt{2^{2^1}+\sqrt{2^{2^2}+\sqrt{2^{2^3}+\cdots}}}}\\A=\sqrt{2+A\sqrt2}\implies A=\frac{\sqrt2+\sqrt{10}}2$$

Thus, $B$ is bounded above, so it converges.

---

One may see $A$ is bounded above since

$$A_1=\sqrt{2^{2^0}}=\sqrt2=\frac{\sqrt2+\sqrt2}2<\frac{\sqrt2+\sqrt{10}}2$$

$$A_2=\sqrt{2^{2^0}+\sqrt{2^{2^1}}}=\sqrt{2+\sqrt2A_1}<\sqrt{2+\sqrt2\frac{\sqrt2+\sqrt{10}}2}=\frac{\sqrt2+\sqrt{10}}2$$

$$A_3=\sqrt{2^{2^0}+\sqrt{2^{2^1}+\sqrt{2^{2^2}}}}=\sqrt{2+\sqrt2A_2}<\sqrt{2+\sqrt2\frac{\sqrt2+\sqrt{10}}2}=\frac{\sqrt2+\sqrt{10}}2$$

And on with the induction.

Comment: Now we have shown that $B$ converges. How about find the exact value of $B$?

Comment: @LCH No idea, probably one of those unsolved things.

Comment: Perhaps related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1548996/this-infinitely-nested-root-gives-me-two-answers-sqrt4-sqrt8-sqrt32-sqr?rq=1